# MacOS export of env var is being escaped or misinterpreted on shell

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, env-file

Mac OS here. On the terminal, I create the following `.env` file:

```
export FIZZ=foo
export BUZZ="$2a$10$Hk1PB6Eyf5Pu71JLfH6fCexjzOIwkctk.pQJ4oYWP.m4qdRKRQlyO"
```

Then I run `source .env && echo $FIZZ` and I see:

```
foo
```

So far, so good. But now I run `echo $BUZZ` and the output is:

```
a0.pQJ4oYWP.m4qdRKRQlyO
```

I explicitly put the value for `BUZZ` in double quotes (`"$2a$10$Hk1PB6Eyf5Pu71JLfH6fCexjzOIwkctk.pQJ4oYWP.m4qdRKRQlyO"`), so why is it outputting as `"a0.pQJ4oYWP.m4qdRKRQlyO"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce what you saw.  I'm pretty sure you're having issues with the environment variable substitution that bash does.  (triggered by the "$" character.)  I know of two ways to "fix" it.

One is to escape the "$" characters with a preceding backslash.
`export BUZZ=\$2a\$10\$Hk1PB6Eyf5Pu71JLfH6fCexjzOIwkctk.pQJ4oYWP.m4qdRKRQlyO`

Another is to change the way you quote the string.  Use single quotes instead of double quotes...
`export BUZZ='$2a$10$Hk1PB6Eyf5Pu71JLfH6fCexjzOIwkctk.pQJ4oYWP.m4qdRKRQlyO'`.

The double quotes allow environment variable substitution to continue, the single quotes prevent that from occurring.